# During the iOS review process, does Apple use production or development APS notification certificates for testing?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I'm using a third party service and I need to know which p12 file to upload to their servers -- development or distribution?

My app relies heavily on push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload your application for submission to the app store, it should be a production-ready version. Thus it should include your production push certificates.

Comment: Yes, Apple has only access to the production provisioning profile you sign your submission with - which means it must have production push certificates.